Vue Router not allowing slug
When routing in my Vue project i can make it to /signin or /demoList, but i cannot make it to /listView/1 which in the Vue router would be defined as /listView/:id. From understanding i should be able to access that 1 as a router param or consume that value as a prop in the component its loading. However, it doesn't even seem to register
router.js
import { createRouter } from 'vue-router/auto'
import { setupLayouts } from 'virtual:generated-layouts'
import { createWebHashHistory } from 'vue-router';
import Index from "@/pages/index.vue";
import DemoEvent from "@/pages/demoEvent.vue";
import DemoList from "@/pages/demoList.vue";
import Signin from "@/pages/signin.vue";
import Signup from "@/pages/signup.vue";
import Calendar from "@/pages/calendar.vue";
import ListView from "@/pages/listView.vue";

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHashHistory(import.meta.env.BASE_URL),
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      component: Index
    },
    {
      path: '/demoEvent',
      component: DemoEvent
    },
    {
      path: '/demoList',
      component: DemoList
    },
    {
      path: '/listView/:id',
      component: ListView,
      name: 'listView',
      meta: {
        requiresAuth: true
      },
      props: route => ({ id: Number(route.params.id) })
    },
    {
      path: '/calendar',
      component: Calendar
    },
    {
      path: '/signin',
      component: Signin
    },
    {
      path: '/signup',
      component: Signup
    },
  ],
  extendRoutes: setupLayouts,
})

export default router

I don't see anything in this config that should cause any issues although, when I use { createRouter } from 'vue-router/auto' it breaks that particular route (i.e. the problem has been found) the only issue with using vue-router is that it will not automatically setup the layouts i have defined which is not something I can readily go without.
When i route to this from a different component in my app i use the following:
function goToItem(index) {
  router.push(`/listView/${index}`);
}

which returns

[Vue Router warn]: No match found for location with path "/listView/1"

Is there maybe something I'm missing here??

if this is file-based routing you need to have a /listView/[id].vue file for the route to be a match.  I believe this is unplugin's vue-router?  see relevant documentation
